# Ghostscript compatibility question between 8.15 and 8.70

Tags: x86-64, ghostscript, rasterizing

I was using ghostscript 8.15 for pdf rasterization on a x86_64 system. Now because of new features I want to switch to version 8.70. However, I noticed that Ghostscript made a note about supporting only 32 bit postscript integers in version 8.70. I don't quite understand how this could affect the behavior of my application and was wondering if anybody had any ideas or reasons for why I might not want to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thought process and wanted the features in 8.70 (in x86_64).  I setup and installed version 8.70 in CentOS (64) and am having success with it.  I wrote about the build process here: http://chrisschuld.com/2010/01/updating-ghostscript-on-centos-5-4-ghostscript-8-70/

I use ghostscript as part of ImageMagick to raster PDF files and have not had any issues outside of unsupported font challenges.